# Is there a way to read the value of a feature toggle from an external microservice?

Tags: togglz

Currently, we have Togglz set up with our app A. I'm trying to read whether or not a certain feature toggle is enabled from microservice B (in order to allow/disallow traffic from A to access B).

App A points to this endpoint to gather all feature toggles, but I'm unsure of how to access this db from microservice B

````
promiseFeatureData = $.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: '/big-repo/restServices/util/features/app-a',
  dataType: 'json',```
````

Answer (score 0):

Aloha,

did you try the StateRepository in an TogglzConfiguration in Microservice B?  That should enable you to read/write to the state of features.

Cheers

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30366116)